# how to simplify modulo arithmetic expression containing a division operation?

Tags: c++, math, modulo, arithmetic-expressions

my question is very simple.

The expression `((a + b) * c) % m` can be simplified to

```py
= (((a + b) % m) * (c % m)) % m
= ((((a % m) + (b % m)) % m) * (c % m)) % m
```

I am trying to simplify the expression `((a + b) / c) % m`. what would be the simplified modulo form of this?

Comment: The first step is to calculate the inverse of `c` mod m. One possibility is to use the extended Euclidian algorithm.

Comment: @Damien Not if `/ c` means real-numbers division. `2 / 3 % 4` is equal to about 0.666667, whereas `2 * inverse_of_3_mod_4 % 4` is equal to 2. And if `/` means integer division, it's even worse. In that case, `2 / 3 % 4` is equal to 0.

Comment: @Stef Technically you are right. However, during the last 45 years, I have never met an interesting use case with modulo of real numbers. Maybe this time.. I interpreted this problem as operations in the Galois field Z/mZ, where divisions are well defined.

Comment: @Damien Interesting or not, the question is tagged [c++], so `/` must be either integer division or floating-point division, depending on the types of `a+b` and `c`.

Comment: @Damien: Also, even in the integer case the first step has to be to cancel any common factors with (a+b). It may be that gcd(c, m) > 1, but gcd(c/d, m) == 1 where d = gcd(a+b, c).

Comment: @President Effectively. In such problems, m is often prime,... but not always.

Comment: @Damien. m prime does not change the need to cancel common factors. (5+10)/5 mod 5 still has a solution but the denominator 5 is not invertible.